# linux + how to find the unused disk on linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed, perl

I need to find the best approach that search the unused disk in my linux OS

for example from the following ouput we can see that sde is not mounted and seems to be free disk ( we need free disk in order to create on him FS and then mount to some folder )

please advice what is the best approach to find the free disk ? with command line or command line with awk / sed / perl etc , in order to capture the unused disk

**sda is for the OS**

```
lsblk | grep disk | grep -v fd0 
sda                8:0    0   150G  0 disk
sdb                8:16   0    20G  0 disk /jeded
sdc                8:32   0    20G  0 disk /var/mmn
sdd                8:48   0    20G  0 disk /var/nrdd
sde                8:64   0    20G  0 disk
```

**expected output should be sde**

- there are some other command to view the disk as sfdisk -s , or fdisk -l , but what we want to find is which disk is a free disk ( without FS / mounted )

Comment: if you can use presence of `/` to indicate not-free disk, try `lsblk | awk '/disk/ && !/fd0|^sda |\//{print $1}'`

Comment: lsblk | awk '/disk/ && !/fd0|^sda |\//{print $1}' this command print --> 
sde

Comment: but we need to check also if this disk is mount according to the last field

Comment: from the example - expected output should be sde

Comment: that is what you get from my suggestion.. so what is the issue? am not able to follow

Comment: ok . what in case sde is mounted then we cant use it !

Comment: won't the output of `lsblk` be different if `sde` is mounted? it will have `/` in  the entry of sde and awk won't report sde

Comment: ok , so you want to write an answer about this ?

Comment: `lsblk -f` will list the file systems output as well. You can then filter it to display only the ones that doesn't have specific FS type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
lsblk  --noheadings --raw | awk '$1~/s.*[[:digit:]]/ && $7==""'
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 18.04, one option could be to use the command

```
lsblk | grep -v '^loop'
```

The output in my case is

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
└─sda1        8:1    0   1.8T  0 part /raid
nvme1n1     259:0    0   477G  0 disk
nvme0n1     259:1    0   477G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:2    0   800M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:3    0     5G  0 part
└─nvme0n1p3 259:4    0 471.2G  0 part /
```

The output shows that disk `nvme1n1` is not in use and not mounted anywhere.

---

Another command to identify the disk with no partition

```
fdisk -l | grep -v 'Disk /dev/loop' | grep -v '^Units' | grep -v '^Sector' | grep -v 'I/O'
```